# cArray[][] Pointer Array Casting

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I am having trouble with a vendor API for retrieving data from a device.  A working version of the call  as suggested in the vendor docs looks something like the following:

```
int dataArray[15][20];
getData(15, 20, (int*) dataArray);
```

The call signature is described as:

```
void getData(xSize, ySize, int*);
```

I am interested in having this function to copy data into a contiguous array of ints with a dynamic size, with something like the following:

```
int *flatDataArray = (int*) malloc(xSize * ySize * sizeof(int));
```

I am having a hard time getting the call right, and segfaults are somewhat difficult to debug :(

I think my misunderstanding is around how a int array is  represented, and what happens when you cast it to (int*).  In this example is "dataArray" of type int**, or something else?  If so, would you have to construct an array of pointers into flatDataArray for the above function to work properly?

Comment: Pointers can be used to iterate over 1-dimensional arrays, but pointers to pointers can't be used to iterate over 2-dimensional arrays, which are simply arrays of arrays. Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson I believe, they can, as long as the pointer knows that it points to an *array of `n` elements of a type*, not just *pointer of an variable of a type*.

Comment: What is the problem?, the function takes a pointer to double not a pointer to an array of doubles.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: A 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays. Using a pointer-to-pointer doesn't make sense, because there are no pointer *objects* for such a pointer to point to. (Unless you create them yourself.)

Comment: Just pass it as &dataArray[0][0].

Comment: This question's title is potentially confusing. The phrase "double pointer" refers to something of type `double*`, but it's also commonly misused to refer to a pointer-to-pointer. This question refers to both.

Comment: That is really confusing.  Let me change the type for sake of clarity.

Comment: I changed it to int so discussion can be clearer. @this, are can you explain what you mean there?  What actually happens when you pointer cast the array[][]?

Comment: @meawoppl Undefined behaviour.

Comment: you can refer following link http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

Comment: So why then does the first two line version work?

Comment: Because you are unlucky; or your compiler might not strictly comply with c standard.

Comment: @cup That was the other example in the documentation.  Does this dereference the array to the first element, then re-pointerfy it?  Is this a way to just get a pointer to the first element?

Comment: It is if the array is allocated as dataArray[15][20].  It isn't if it is declared as dataArray[15] and each of the elements is allocated an array of 20.

Comment: You still have the confusing phrase "double array" in the title, and several remaining references to `double` even though you changed `double` to `int` in the code.

Comment: @KeithThompson Fixed apologies for any additional confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line "works" because of the cast.

Given:

```
int dataArray[15][20];
getData(15, 20, (int*) dataArray);
```

The expression value *type* of `dataArray` stand-alone is `int (*)[20]`. a pointer to an array of 20 `int`. This makes sense because per the C standard the expression value of an array is the address of its first element and a pointer-to-type of said-same. Well, the first "element" of an array of arrays (which is what `dataArray` is)  is of type `int[20]`, and the pointer-to-type give us `int(*)[20]`.

That said, the same rules apply to the first array in that array of arrays. In short, this will work:

```
int dataArray[15][20];
getData(15, 20, dataArray[0]);
```

Just like `dataArray` is an expression resulting in the address of the first element (an array)  of type `int (*)[20]`, the first array in that array likewise has a expression value which is the address of *its* first element, an `int`, and the type associated to that address is `int *` As it happens, this is the first element of the first array of an array of arrays. In the linear memory backdrop of the underlying system this is running on, it all eventually resolves to the same *address* (where `dataArray` lays in memory). It is the *types* associated with that address, depending on how it is contrived, that are different. Regardless of the types, however, the underlying memory backdrop is the same: a contiguous sequence of 300 `int`. The address returned by **all** of the following will be the same; only the types are different (and noted in comment)

```
&dataArray            // int (*)[15][20]
dataArray             // int (*)[20]
dataArray[0]          // int *
&dataArray[0][0]      // int *
```

and no, these aren't the only combinations. I left at least one out. See if you can figure out what is missing.

Anyway, allocating as you are here:

```
int *flatDataArray = malloc(xSize * ySize * sizeof(int));
```

works because you're simply building a `xSize by ySize` linear backdrop. Because this is C, the following would also work, utilizing the VLA (variable length array) feature of the language:

```
int (*arr2D)[ySize] = malloc(xSize * sizeof(*arr2D));
```

assuming `xSize` is the number of *rows*, and `ySize` is the number of *columns* you seek (I seem get that wrong half the time, which is why I prefer the monikers "row" and "col"). The above allocation says "Allocate me space for `xSize` number of `int[ySize]` things.". The benefit in-code is you can address this just as you would a 2D array of arrays (which is exactly what it is):

```
arr2d[i][j] = value;
```

for any `i` in `0..(xsize-1)` and `j` in `0..(ysize-1)`, just like you would/could as if you declared it normally. This (VLAs) is one thing C does well that C++ does not (but then again, there are containers-o-plenty in C++ that would have solved this problem a different way in the first place, so it isn't really a fair comparison).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2 dimensional array declared as the following:

```
double dataArray[15][20];
```

The flattened out version would simply be the following:

```
dataArray[0];
```

And if you were to store this *address of the first double* into a *pointer (address variable) to a double*:

```
double * flatDataArray = dataArray[0];
```

The following loop, for example, accesses every single element in a contiguous manner, thanks to the fact that they already were contiguous and never in multi-dimensions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15 * 20; i++) {
    dataArray[0][i];    // alternatively: flatDataArray[i];
```

As per the edit: Change all that `double` to `int`, or whatever type you wish.

Say that it was of `char`s, here's how it would look like, and what `dataArray`, `*dataArray` and `**dataArray` would resemble:

```
   char0  char1  ...  char14  char15  char16  ...  char29  ...  char299
// >                             dataArray                            <
// >     *dataArray        <  >                         <               
// >   <  >   <
//   ^ the **dataArray
```

The `dataArray` may not get *dereferenced* more, twice max. By taking the address of `**dataArray`, you'll have `*dataArray` on your hands. Similar for `*dataArray`. Not for `dataArray`, in which case you'll rather have simply `&dataArray`.

Each one of `&dataArray`, `dataArray` and `*dataArray` will have the same *value*, which is the address of `char0`, or the array that spans from `char0` to `char14`, or the array of arrays that spans from `char0-char14` to `char285-char299`.

`**dataArray` will have the value that `char0` holds.

What's the difference between the other three? Well, they point to different types, hence incrementing them will have different interpretations. This is similar to how, when you increment an integer pointer, you advance 4 bytes instead of 1.

If you happen to increment `&dataArray` by 1, like `&dataArray + 1`, you'd advance 300 bytes (`300 * sizeof(char)`). If you happen to increment `dataArray` by 1, which is the address of `*dataArray`, you'd advance 15 bytes, and so on.

If you happen to increment the `*dataArray` by 1, which is the address of `**dataArray` the `char0`, you'd advance 1 byte. Now, here's what:

- `*dataArray` is `dataArray[0]`
- incrementing it by 1 is `dataArray[0] + 1`
- that dereferenced would be `*(dataArray[0] + 1)`
- shorthand for that is `dataArray[0][1]`
- say we were to increment it more, say, 15 times in total
- `dataArray[0][15]`

Seems illegal, doesn't it? Well, it's not, because that bit of the memory is still within the part allocated for you. In fact, you can go as far as `dataArray[0][299]`. It just means *advance 299 bytes, and access that location*, and that location is all yours.

Crazy, isn't it? Even more crazy that I've wrote so much about it. I'm not even sure if this answers your question anymore... I suppose a call like `getData(15, 20, dataArray[0]);` or `getData(15, 20, *dataArray);` would therefore be more sensible, although I doubt that a typecast there would fail.

I hope this at least will make sense to someone.

Comment: Much thanks for the thoroughness.  Between this answer and the comments I think I have what I need to piece this all together.  The important insight is that depending on how the vendor implemented the function, the passed pointer could have one of two semantics.  I believe that because the size is not known to the API at compile time, there must be some manual under the hood pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine:

```
int dataArray[15][20];
getData(15, 20, (int*) dataArray);
```

and it works because you are viewing the entire object `dataArray` via a pointer to int; and since dataArray does contain ints, there aren't any aliasing violations.

It would be undefined behaviour to write `getData(15, 20, dataArray[0]);` because in this case you are using a pointer to only the array of 20 ints which was the first element of dataArray, so you aren't allowed to overflow those 20 ints. (Ref: C99 6.5.6#8)

> I am interested in having this function to copy data into a contiguous array of doubles with a dynamic size

`int` and `double` are different, so you cannot pass any sort of array of `double` to this function (as you have described the function anyway; if this function actually takes `void *` and then outputs data based on some previous function call, that would be different). Unless the API also includes a function that takes a pointer to `double`, you have to retrieve the `int`s and then convert them to double. For example,

```
int array1[xSize][ySize];
getData( (int *)int_array );

double array2[xSize][ySize];
for ( size_t ii = 0; ii < xSize; ++ii )
    for ( size_t jj = 0; jj < ySize; ++jj )
         array2[xSize][ySize] = array1[xSize][ySize];
```

The last line performs a value conversion from `int` to `double`.

In C arrays can have runtime dimensions like this. (Actually in 2011 this was changed to be an optional feature, previously it was standard).  If you are using a compiler which no longer supports this sort of array you can use `malloc`.

If both dimensions are not known at compile-time, then you have to malloc a 1-D array and then work out offsets into it; e.g.

```
int *array1 = malloc(xSize * ySize * sizeof *array1);
getData(array1);

double *array2 = malloc(xSize * ySize * sizeof *array2);
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < xSize * ySize; ++ii)
    array2[ii] = array1[ii];

// what was previously array1[4][6]
array2[4 * ySize + 6];
```

NB. `void getData(xSize, ySize, int*);` is not a valid call signature. A call signature would have data types instead of variable names. You could find the function declaration in the header file you are including to access this API.